# nunit3-console doesn't see DLLs from Microsoft.AspNETCore.App

Tags: c#, nunit, .net-8.0

When I run UTs from Visual Studio all runs fine but when I need to run it with `nunit3-console My.Tests.dll` I see `FileNotFoundException` like this

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Xml, ...

I see them only for DLLs from `Microsoft.AspNETCore.App` folder, DLLs from `Microsoft.NETCore.App` are loaded fine.

The test file

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    Assembly.Load("System.Security.Cryptography.Xml, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51");
}
```

If I explicitly load then tests run fine

```
Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\shared\\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\\8.0.0\\System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.dll");
```

Comment: What version of NUnit3-Console are you using?

Comment: @Charlie _NUnit Console 3.17.0+685c5b542b5e9ba632c905f0bd514a773d9758af (Release)_

Answer (score 0):

Look like its an inner issue with `NUNIT3-CONSOLE`'s how the runtime locates assemblies, read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies).

It can be solve easily with using the dotner cli with `dotnet test`.

If you must use it (would be happy to know why), you can try to modify the [runtime configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/). `[YourTestAssembly].runtimeconfig.json` something like:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp3.1",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "3.1.0"
    },
}
```

Change the target verion number.